# cannot be cast to ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring, runnable, threadpoolexecutor

I have to write a class which is accept the socket connection and pass it to Handler class using Spring

My Listener Class is

```
public class Listener {

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Listener.class.getName());

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    int port = 0;
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java -jar hovel.jar listenPortNumber");
            System.exit(1);
        } else {
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }
         ApplicationContext context = 
                 new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
            ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = (ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) context.getBean("TCPHandler");

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Listening on TCP port " + port);
        for (;;) {
            Socket sock = serverSocket.accept();
            taskExecutor.execute(new TCPHandler(sock));

        }
    }

}
```

My Handler class is

```
public class TCPHandler implements Runnable {
    private Socket moduleSocket;



    public TCPHandler(Socket sock) {
        moduleSocket = sock;
    }

    public void run() {

    }

}
```

My Bean.xml is

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="TCPHandler" class="org.hovel.server.TCPHandler">
   <constructor-arg type="java.net.Socket">
        <null />
    </constructor-arg>
   </bean>
   <bean id="taskExecutor"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

when i pass port number then i got this error 

**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.hovel.server.TCPHandler cannot be cast to
>   org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  at
>   org.hovel.server.Listener.main(Listener.java:27)*

**

Please Help Me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're requesting the `TCPHandler` bean here:

```
context.getBean("TCPHandler")
```

That *isn't* a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`, so I don't know why you expect it to be. If you want to retrieve the executor, you should be fetching *that* bean instead, which has an ID of `taskExecutor`.

Note that currently you're not actually using your `TCPHandler` bean in any useful way, as you're constructing a `TCPHandler` explicitly in your `main` method.